# Is it possible to exclude some files from rm -rf?

Tags: command-line, bash, rm, sh

I have a directory that I is filled by another user, and I'm tasked with maintaining it. I want to delete all its content except a 2 files with a specific name. Is it possible with `rm` or should I do this:

```
cp aaa/a ./a && cp aaa/b ./b && rm -rf aaa/* && mv ./a aaa/a && mv ./b aaa/b
```

where `aaa` is the directory, `a,b` are the files I want to keep, and there are (at least, there may be) other files/directories in there.

Is there a better (and shorter) way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232634/2920227

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With bash extended globs, given

```
$ tree aaa
aaa
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
├── e
└── subdir
```

then

```
rm -rf aaa/!(a|b)
```

leaves

```
$ tree aaa
aaa
├── a
└── b

0 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Cool! is there a way to use this also in `sh`? I'm getting there `-sh: !: event not found`

Comment: Based on the error message, you're actually using it in `bash` but with the extended glob feature disabled - in a script, you may need to add `shopt -s extglob` at the top. But no, AFAIK you can't do the same in POSIX `sh` / `dash`