# mv: missing destination file operand after with grep

Tags: bash, mv

Kia ora,

I have a build script where I do a bunch of file operations and if they succeed, I print stuff to stdout as part of a report generated for the build. However I am getting the error "mv: missing destination file operand after" a lot.

```
if mv $(ls *.md | grep -v _index.md) markdown; then
    echo "    Put Markdown files back in 'markdown'"
fi
```

I have been reading that it is usually people have just missed the destination part of the command, but in this case I don't *think* that I have.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You should really avoid constructs like `$(ls *.md | grep -v _index.md)` - in bash, you could more robustly set the `nullglob` and `extglob` options i.e. `shopt -s nullglob extglob` and then use `mv -t markdown/ !(_index).md` I think

Comment: ... the error could simply be because `ls *.md | grep -v _index.md` returns no matches, so that your command becomes `mv markdown`

Comment: I think that is what is happening, too! Is there a way to avoid the grumbly error?

Answer (score 3):

Likely the error is because `$(ls *.md | grep -v _index.md)` evaluates to an empty string (i.e. there are no `.md` files that do not match `_index.md`) so that your command becomes

```
mv markdown
```

In general, you should avoid constructions like `$(ls *.md | grep -v _index.md)` for the reasons discussed here:

- [Bash Pitfall #1: $(ls *.mp3)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Bash has a couple of nice "globbing" features that allow you to avoid such problems:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob extglob

mdfiles=( !(_index).md )

if (( ${#mdfiles[@]} > 0 )); then
  if mv -t markdown/ -- "${mdfiles[@]}"; then
    echo "    Put Markdown files back in 'markdown'"
  fi
else
  echo "    No Markdown files to move"
fi
```

This should work unless the number of `.md` files is large enough to overflow the shell's `ARG_MAX`.

See also

- [What is the purpose of shopt -s extglob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob)
- [Is it possible to exclude some files from rm -rf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053241/is-it-possible-to-exclude-some-files-from-rm-rf/1053242#1053242)

Comment: @pLumo good one - added